# Outlook 2010 - VBA - Drag to Explorer

Tags: vba, drag-and-drop, outlook, metadata

I would like to capture the Drag Outlook Item to Desktop / Explorer event and change the file name that gets saved.  Is this possible through a VBA script in Outlook?

Additionally, I would also like to add some Document Meta Data to the file, so that the Subject, To, From, etc columns in Explorer would be populated.

Thanks

Comment: I had to write a VBA macro to Save out the selected email to a msg file and use some DSOFile OleDocumentProperties to set the meta data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such event or method is exposed by the Outlook Object Model.